# Pip3 is unable to install requirements.txt during docker build

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I am using docker tutorial (https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/) to build a simple python app. Using `freeze` command I made `requirements.txt` file which consists a lot of packages.

When I want to build the docker image, I am getting this error:

> Step 4/6 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt  ---> Running in
> f92acd21d271
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> apt-clone==0.2.1 (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for apt-clone==0.2.1
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a
> non-zero code: 1

This is my dockerfile contents (same as what is mentioned in the tutorial):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "-m", "flask","run","--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

It's not related to apt-clone==0.2.1 package. Whatever I try to install in the docker image, it fails. I tried apt update and installing pip3 in the dockerfile too but didn't work.

What did I miss?

Comment: try recreating the steps in your Dockerfile in interactive mode `docker run -it --rm python:3.8-slim-buster`. this has usually helped me (non-Py projects). let me know if you need elaborate instructions. it wouldn't fit in comments

Comment: @kevinnls Could you please elaborate your idea as an answer?

Comment: He basically means `docker run --rm -it python:3.8-slim-buster --name something bash` and then manually `docker cp requirements.txt something:/app` etc to trace the steps of the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: yes that ..... and go thru various troubleshooting steps. but we already have the answer :) cheers! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip3 freeze` outputs the package and its version installed in the current environment, no matter the package installed by `pip` or with other methods.

In fact, `apt-clone==0.2.1` comes from debian package repo, not from `pypi.org`, see next:

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep apt-clone
$ apt-get install -y apt-clone
$ dpkg -l apt-clone
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  apt-clone      0.4.1        all          Script to create state bundles
$  dpkg -L apt-clone
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/apt-clone
/usr/share/doc/apt-clone/copyright
/usr/share/doc/apt-clone/changelog.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/apt-clone.8.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_clone.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_clone-0.2.1.egg-info
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/apt-clone
$ pip3 freeze | grep apt-clone
apt-clone==0.2.1
```

You could see from above, the `apt_clone.py` & `apt_clone-0.2.1.egg-info` are installed by debian package `apt-clone`, the `0.4.1` is just the debian package version, while `0.2.1` is the python package version.

So, for `apt-clone` similar, you need to install them with `apt` although they are seen in `pip3 freeze`.

Comment: From `dpkg -L apt-clone` we could see what `apt-clone.deb` be installed, `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_clone.py` & `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_clone-0.2.1.egg-info` means they are python packages.

Comment: Yes as @tripleee pointed out, these are debian packages not the python packages, but apparently the point is that "pip freeze" is not a good tool for building a docker image.

Comment: `apt-clone.deb` of course not python package, but when it be extracted to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, it becomes python package. You can verify it by delete `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_clone-0.2.1.egg-info`, after delete the `egg info`, it nolonger be shown in `pip3 freeze`.

Comment: Except don't mess with `/usr/lib` contents on a production system.

Comment: The delete of `egg-info` is just to let you verify this is really a python package, as you thought it's not a python package in your comments. After confirm it's a python package, then you can understand why it be shown in `pip freeze`. But, YES, you shouldn't try to delete all `egg-info` as you even can't confirm which to delete or which not to delete. Still, the solution is: you need to know what package needed for your environment, and write your own requirements.txt.

Answer (score 3):

There is no package named `apt-clone` in the public PyPI repository, so `pip3` obviously cannot find it.

If you actually have a Python package named like this, where did it come from?

- If you created a package with this name locally, you need to install it too in your Docker image somehow.
- If you are inside an organization, maybe you have a local PyPI with different packages than the public one, and then you need to configure `pip3` to use it (try `pip3 -i http://your.local.pypi/simple -r requirements.txt` where obviously the URL needs to be something else, but we can't guess what).

If `pip3 freeze` says you have this package, it must have come from somewhere, but we don't know where. You have to figure that out, or supply more details to help us help you.

There is a Debian package named `apt-clone` but that obviously isn't something `pip` can install. Did you actually mean `apt-get install -y apt-clone==0.2.1`? (I can only find version 0.4.1 in Debian Buster, though.)

... @atline's answer explains what happened (you should probably accept that) but the simple fix is to manually populate `requirements.txt` with your *actual* requirements.  `pip3 freeze` is a nice shorthand for that if you are in a virtual environment, but it's not a proper replacement for a manually curated `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` (or its modern replacements, currently moving from `setup.cfg` to `pyproject.toml`).  If `flask` is the only package your app needs, simply put `pip3 install flask` and don't create a `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't put apt-clone in the list, I just did a "pip3 freeze" to make the list and it listed apt-clone==0.2.1! As I mentioned if I remove this package, the same error exists with the next one too (like apturl==0.5.2) and so on

Comment: Again, there is no public PyPI package named `apturl` but there is an Ubuntu package with that name. I can only speculate as to how `pip freeze` would come up with names of packages which are unknown to the external world, and have already done so in this answer. How did you build the environment where you ran `pip3 freeze` in the first place?

Comment: Yes apparently there is a mismatch between packages I installed on my OS (mint 20) and  the python packages, but I am wondering what should I do to resolve it! The only thing I did was the freeze command (exactly as the documentation which I referred to)

Comment: Regarding the number of problematic packages I am wondering why the docker website didn't consider such situation.

Comment: It's still not clear what situation you are talking about. If Mint provides packages which are not part of PyPI then you need to create a Mint-based container or figure out how to import their packages. But this doesn't sound feasible; Mint is pretty close to Debian actually.

Comment: The instructions probably assume that you developed your app in a virtual environment, where `pip3 freeze` will only print the actual dependencies specific to your package.

Comment: As you mentioned the problem is related to pip freeze. I don't know why pip freeze should list everything from OS. Along with your explanation I found this link helpful (https://medium.com/@tomagee/pip-freeze-requirements-txt-considered-harmful-f0bce66cf895)

Comment: Clearly not a good assumption from the instruction!

Comment: It should probably be clearer about it, but this is common practice.