# ERROR: Service 'service' failed to build : Build failed

Tags: docker, fastapi

I have 2 docker files. I cant build by project FastApi + PostgreSQL. I need run my fastapi app

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_ok
    expose: 
      - 5432

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
# RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Also i have requirements.txt file

Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apt-

clone==0.2.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apt-clone==0.2.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

How to fix tihs problem??

Comment: How exactly does the build fail?  Can you [edit] the question to include the complete error?

Comment: `apt-clone` in fact [doesn't exist on PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=apt-clone), so that seems like a reasonable error.  Can you install your project in a non-Docker virtual environment?

Comment: Also see [Pip3 is unable to install requirements.txt during docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67798862/pip3-is-unable-to-install-requirements-txt-during-docker-build).